# Django retrieve a list of items from form

Tags: python, django

I have a quiz view that displays a list of questions and textarea for students to key in their answers. As I'm new to Django, I wonder what is the correct way to get the list of students answers from the post method? Here is my current code:

forms.py

```
class TakeTestForm(forms.Form):
    student_answer = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label='')
```

views.py

```
class TakeTestFormView(FormView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        submit_answer_form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if submit_answer_form.is_valid():
            answer_list = request.POST['student_answer'] ?? # TODO: Retrieve list of answers from the form
```

index.html

```
{% for question in qst_data %}
     <div id="action-container">
              {{ take_test_form.as_p }}
     </div>
% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#field-data) info from official django docs will be useful for you. After validating django forms all fields' data can and should be retrieved from `cleaned_data` dictionary. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#accessing-clean-data) is info that explain the reason for it:

> Each field in a Form class is responsible not only for validating data, but also for “cleaning” it – normalizing it to a consistent format. This is a nice feature, because it allows data for a particular field to be input in a variety of ways, always resulting in consistent output.